# Python function for finding individual elements in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of days with repeated entries (as in the example shown below). I don't know what's in the list, as it is provided by the user.

1. 2022-07-20
2. 2022-07-20
3. 2022-07-20
4. 2022-07-21
5. 2022-07-22
6. 2022-07-22
7. 2022-07-22
8. 2022-07-22
9. 2022-07-23
10. 2022-07-23

I want to get all the individual entries in the list, without necessarely knowing how many times they appear (in other words I want to know that there is at least one of each of the entries). The output should look something like this:

1. 2022-07-20
2. 2022-07-21
3. 2022-07-22
4. 2022-07-23

Is there a python function to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a Set with your list, as sets are collections of unique objects:

```
l=[1,2,2,3,3,3]
s=set(l)
print(s)
{1, 2, 3}
```